# How is JSON number encoded?

Tags: json

How is number represented in JSON internally and how many bytes of data does it take to store a JSON number?

I can't find any info specifying this internal detail.

Comment: A legit question downvoted, stop the madness pls.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the ECMA standard (PDF)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), §8:

> A number is represented in base 10 with no superfluous leading zero. It may have a preceding minus sign (U+002D). It may have a (U+002E) prefixed fractional part. It may have an exponent of ten, prefixed by e (U+0065) or E (U+0045) and optionally + (U+002B) or – (U+002D). The digits are the code points U+0030 through U+0039.

So, pretty much text, except that (later on the page) `NaN` and `Infinity` aren't acceptable values.

[BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), however, has `int32`, `int64`, and `double` types that are a bit more traditional.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a data interchange format. It is just text. There is no "internal" representation of JSON, unless you are referring to how your particular system encodes and stores text data.

The number of bytes it takes to store a JSON number would be the length of the number, in characters, multiplied by the number of bytes required to store a character in your particular system.